# Curve rubric entry key with line break

Tags: line-breaking, curve-class

I am using the curve class to make a resume.  I would like to have an entry key inside a rubric that goes over two lines, like this (notice the line break in `Arts \& \\ crafts`):

```
% resume.tex
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{curve}

\begin{document}
\makerubric{skills}
\end{document}

% skills.tex
\begin{rubric}{Skills}
\entry*[Languages]%
    English, Orc, Whale.
\entry*[Arts \& \\ crafts]%
    Pencil, colored pencils, acrylic, oil, scrap metal, toothpicks, stickers, water pastels, crayons, beads, thread, cloth, paperclips, leaves, bubblewrap, etc.
\end{rubric}
```

The problem is that the entry text (`Pencil, colored...`) starts on the second line with `crafts` instead of on the first line with `Arts \&`, leaving extra whitespace and resulting in a total of three lines for the entry instead of two.  **How do I get the entry text to line up with the first line of the entry key?**

UPDATE: The following is closer to the desired output but still not quite there:

```
% resume.tex
\documentclass[letter,11pt]{curve}
\usepackage{calc} % provides \widthof

\begin{document}
\makerubric{skills}
\end{document}

% skills.tex
\begin{rubric}{Skills}
\entry*[Languages]%
    English, Orc, Whale.
\entry*[\begin{minipage}{\widthof{Arts \&}}Arts \& \\ crafts\end{minipage}]%
    Pencil, colored pencils, acrylic, oil, scrap metal, toothpicks, stickers, water pastels, crayons, beads, thread, cloth, paperclips, leaves, bubblewrap, etc.
\end{rubric}
```

However, adding any of the `[t]`, `[c]`, or `[b]` arguments to `minipage` makes the whole thing crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer, I am facing the same issue only now. The documentation of the CurVe package gives the answer in the appendix:

> - Recover the key formatting by doing something like this near the beginning of your document:
>   `\makeatletter\let\mykeyfont\@keyfont\makeatother`
> - Use something like this where you need a multi-line key (you will have to adjust the paragraph width manually):
>   `\entry*[\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{\mykeyfont}p{2cm}}{% long key\newline long key}] Entry text.`

Regards.

Comment: Using the suggested code verbatim gives me an error, but if I just use `\entry*[\multicolumn{1}{@{}>{}p{2cm}}{% long key\newline long key}] Entry text` (i.e., leaving out `\mykeyfont`) without the stuff from the first bullet it works fine.  If you let me add that to your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Just discovered that the error was due to a backslash that disappeared somehow.  Actually using it as is works as well.

Comment: The entry keys are right aligned to each other by default. This command makes those left aligned. how to fix that?